# asp.net MVC - Custom Validation based on conditions with client side validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations, customvalidator

I need to change the regex of an item based on certain conditions.

For ex.: I need to change the regex of zip code field based on the Country selection.

Below is what I have for the Zip code as a default inside the Model, which is applicable for USA:

```
[RegularExpression(@"(^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$)|(^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{1} *\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}$)", ErrorMessage="Enter valid Zip Code")]
public string Zip { get; set; }
```

I need to change the regex for the Zip Code when the country is Canada as:

```
@"^([A-PR-UWYZ0-9][A-HK-Y0-9][AEHMNPRTVXY0-9]?[ABEHMNPRVWXY0-9]? {1,2}[0-9][ABD-HJLN-UW-Z]{2}|GIR 0AA)$"
```

I'll be able to get the Country only when the User sign in to the application. How can I change the regex of the zip code programmatically based on the Country chosen? Similarly there are more fields that needs to have regex changed based on Country. Also it should have the client validation. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom validation attribute in C# and then add client-side validation in `$.validator`. You can use [this link](http://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/tag/custom-unobtrusive-validation/) (I think this is very helpful article about custom validation in MVC)

Comment: I just need to replace the regex for some of the fields. Is there any simple way to replace just the regex instead of writing a Custom Validator for each of the fields?

Comment: @Prasad, I think you can't change attribute value in runtime

Answer (score 0):

I think I would use the RemoteValidation Attribute:

```
[Remote("IsZipValid", "SomeController", AdditionalFields = "UserCountry")]
public string Zip { get; set; }
```

And pass the user country as an additional parameter.

```
public JsonResult IsZipValid(
            string zip,
            string userCountry)
{
         // Now you can get the appropriate Regex based on the user's country
        // and return true / false.
}
```

You also mentioned you only know the user country once they have logged in, so you might not even need the additional parameter because the sever will know the user to be able to get the country.

This will send an AJAX request from the web page when the user has entered a zip code, passing their country as a parameter.